# Designing Pixelated Triangle Effect in illustrator

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to design a pixelated Traingle effect in the illustrator i can able to achieve through effects but is there any actions scripts for the illustrator because i need to achieve the exact triangle effect.But i tried is some what some what squeezy

[image]

Is there any way to achieve like above image where each triangle should be as path vector

[image]

This is what i tried using one of the free action script the triangle is not equaly arranged

Comment: Canvas would seem a better technology for this. Write the image to canvas read each triangle's pixels and replace them all by an average colour. If you're just trying to find a tool to do this rather than write an program then your question is off-topic.

Comment: have you tried http://scriptographer.org/? Although its development was discontinued and replaced by Paper.js

Comment: Is there any way to achieve in illustrator apart from Scripts